# How can a I get a link to a raw data file?

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a couple of visualizations of data, and I am trying to make it so I can put it on github so a couple of other people can see it as well. Right now I was using a link with the localhost, and I don't know how to change it so that if someone else downloads the file they can view the html page.

I tried linking the raw github file directly, however, the token at the end changes so this didn't work.

Comment: Is it a public or private repository in GitHub? With a public repo you can get a link to the raw file which should work.

Comment: @DanielWardin it is private. Is it not possible to do with a private repo?

Comment: Not with a private repo. That's the point of it, so it can't be freely accessed by the general public - that's why the tokens on the end of the URL change. You can set up a free AWS account and they provide free S3 storage, create an account, create an S3 bucket, upload the file, select it and make it public. Copy the URL form S3 and voila!